# Ember search engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, seo, phantomjs

I am creating an Ember app that has a search engine built into it say for houses. My results change a lot as houses are found / added or removed / sold. Therefore my search results change all the time.

I also have pages for each house which has a similar houses section on it that shows always changing similar houses to this one.

I am trying to find the best way to make this app crawlable to search engines.

I could like discourse use noscript tages for each page but as all my houses pages can hold different information and structure depending on the agent/ seller this would be a lot more work basically duplicating what the client is doing!

I could go down the phantomjs route and cache all my pages and serve via the escapedfragment_ method but i am thinking this would be a resource intensive approach with content changing so much. Also with my house pages having similar houses on them that can change depending on the user / location etc, i am not sure how to cache these sections.

Another method i am toying with is to convert my page / section templates into a serverside template so i can render it on the server. For example when a customer creates a house page via my ember app in the format they require they click publish and i convert the rendered html into serverside template with placeholders etc for data.

Anyone help with this ? Any ideas / suggestions / advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've kind of answered your own question.  This is all about trade offs and finding the solution that is best for your particular case.  There is no silver bullet.  Personally I go with something close to the `noscript` route, but instead of putting things inside `noscript` tags, I put them in regular divs with a class of `no-ember`, which are visible by default.  Then when the document is ready I test to see if the client supports push state.  If so, I initialize my Ember app and hide the `no-ember` divs.  If not, then all of the `no-ember` divs are visible so that the client can see/use the content like normal.